# how can I filter NSMutableArray as example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, filter, nsmutablearray

I am having an NSMutableArray as my original array and I want to filter it out with its keyvalue pair but only certain keyvalue pair as shown in example.

I don't want to use looping logic. Is there any other way to get the required output? 
I don't want to modify my original array.

```
original array{
                "name" = "name";
                "end_date" = "test end date";
                "id" = 104;
                "start_date" = "test start date";
                "user_id" = 5;
              },
              {
                 "name" = "name1";
                "end_date" = "test1 end date";
                "id" = 105;
                "start_date" = "test1 start date";
                "user_id" = 5;
            }


want filtered array as
{
        "name" = "name";
        "end_date" = "test end date";
        "start_date" = "test start date";

}
}
         "name" = "name";
        "end_date" = "test end date";
        "start_date" = "test start date";
}
```

How Can I achieve this without using for loop?

Comment: Does the array contain mutable dictionaries or immutable dictionaries?

Comment: mine is too long array that is why not going for loop

Comment: yes it do have dictionaries within

Comment: how? i have used predicate as  `filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id LIKE [cd] '%d'",inttag]];
    arrTempArray = [mutarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];` but how to use for more keyvalue pairs?

Comment: mean as u said u want only three keys na

Comment: yes.I only want certain keys for all dictionary of that NSMutableArray

Comment: Joshua's answer below is as close as you're going to get to correct and deserves the tick, but it'll basically do the same thing as a for loop in the framework and if it's total footprint you're worried about, you'll be doing worse than before because you'll now have partial second copies of all the original dictionaries. Are you sure you've thought your requirements through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock using something like this (I didn't enumerate all the keys from the NSDictionary:

```
    NSMutablArray *myNewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
   [myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSDictionary *myNewDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[obj valueForKey:@"name"],@"name"]];
            [myNewArray addObject:myNewDict];
   }];
```

If you wanted just a subset of the elements, you could use an NSPredicate.

Comment: I want more than one keyvalue pairs.So how conveniently use nspredicate here?

Comment: nspredicates can't modify datastructures, they can only query.  So if you want to return array elements that are different (different keys) you probably should use enumeration.

Comment: `NSMutableArray *myNewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [aMutArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj,NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        NSDictionary *mynewdice = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[obj valueForKey:@"name"],@"name",,[obj valueForKey:@"start_date"],@"startdate",[obj valueForKey:@"end_date"],@"enddate"];
        [myNewArray addObject:mynewdice];
    }];`  used this code but gives error as `incompatible block pointer types initializing void(^)(struct NSDictionary *,NSUIInteger,BOOL *) expected void(^)(struct obj_object *,NSUIInteger,BOOL *)`

Comment: i forgot a * in the block signature.  I just edited it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are the dictionaries mutable? And are you looking to modify the original array in place or create a new array?

The easiest solution if your setup allows it would be:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
         ^(id obj, NSUinteger idx, BOOL *stop)
         {
              [obj removeObjectsForKeys:
                  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"id", @"userid", nil]
              ];
         }
];
```

Though a for loop solution would look almost identical.

From a KVC point of view you could use `valueForKey:` to extract separate arrays of each field you want to keep with no explicit loop, but I can't think of a quick way to integrate those three arrays cleanly into one array of three-entry dictionaries.

Comment: I am just filtering out so no worry whether dictionaries are mutable or not. and I could not modify my original array